# mysql with date function query running slow

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I found something weird while executing query today and i want to know how this happens.

Below is my query:

```
select sum(price) as total from table_a where testing_date = '2020-06-10'
```

this query takes 2-5 seconds while searching for the data. Now i did small change in the query as follow:

```
select sum(price) as total from table_a where date(testing_date) = '2020-06-10'
```

In this case query takes 2-3 minutes. Here testing_date column data in dateTime format for example : 2020-06-01 00:00:00

Here total records size is more than 7 million.

Comment: You no longer filter by indexed data?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález,  I have added index on column

Comment: You haven't shared your DB structure but you don't seem to have a [function based index](https://dasini.net/blog/2019/03/14/mysql-functional-indexes/) for `DATE(testing_date)`. If you don't want to add one you need to rewrite your query to make use of the existing one.

Comment: What is the datatype of `testing_date`?

Comment: @RickJames datatype of testing_date is `datetime`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a function on the column you filter on. This makes the query non-SARGeable, meaning that the database cannot take advantage of an existing index. Basically, you are forcing the database to do the computation on each and every value in the column *before* the filtering can happen.

If you want to filter on a given day, you can use inequalities with half-open intervals:

```
where testing_date >= '2020-06-10' and testing_date < '2020-06-11'
```

Comment: what would be the best case **where testing_date = '2020-06-10'** or your solution ?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a;  for confirmation of the column's datatype.

Comment: @MiteshBhanushali: if your dates have no `time` portion, then ` testing_date = '2020-06-10' ` is fine. My suggestion was in case the dates have a time part.

Comment: If it is DATETIME, you are checking against just midnight.

Comment: @RickJames Can you give me an example like from what time will it be start searching

Comment: @MiteshBhanushali Please understand that is would be helpful if you could post SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a to minimize questions and answers by multiple people who care about helping you be successful with your Date selection coding.